# Logics issue while using accelerometer

Tags: java, android, accelerometer

I am trying to make an app like "Heads up" just for more exercising!!

but now I faced some logical problem in using accelerometer in my app.

I want the app toast "correct" when it tilt's down (accelerometer gives -7 in this position) and toast "wrong" when tilt's up (accelerometer gives 7 or more in this position).

But the problem was that app toast many times repeatedly in each position. so I used a boolean (isToasted) to make the app toast once in each of those position. But now it doesn't toast at all!

where is my problem and what should i do?

this is a part of my codes:

```
Boolean isToasted = false;

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    int sensorValue = (int) event.values[2];

    while (isToasted) {
        switch (sensorValue) {
            case 7: {
                Toast.makeText(find_word2.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                isToasted = true;
                break;
            }
            case -7: {
                Toast.makeText(find_word2.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                isToasted = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (sensorValue == 0) isToasted = false;  //sensorValue = 0 means device is not tilted and it's in direct position.
}
```

Comment: any error logs or stack trace ?

Comment: there is no error log

Comment: isToasted will never be true with your current code. It is set to false by default.

Comment: Correct!, isToasted is initialized as false, your while loop condition will always be false.

Comment: so this is why i set (isToasted = true;) in loop to change it to true. is that wrong?

Comment: but to get into the loop that condition has to be true.

Comment: my suggestion would be, use if else before loop to toggle isToasted, for example   if (sensorValue == 0){ isToasted = false; } else {isToasted = true;} then let the loop take care of it.

Comment: "while (isToasted){}" means that it can get into the loop whit any default value it has, and in this case it's default value is false

Comment: while(isToasted) is checking the condition, it'll run while isToasted is true, but isToasted is false to begin with.

Comment: I'd say try do while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it would display the `Toast` multiple times in each position is because a `SensorEvent` can occur [multiple times](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html#onSensorChanged(android.hardware.SensorEvent)) at a single position:

> Note that "on changed" is somewhat of a misnomer, as this will also be
>   called if we have a new reading from a sensor with the exact same
>   sensor values (but a newer timestamp).

Therefore, every time there is a `SensorEvent` that has one of the z-values you specified in your switch statement a `Toast` will be displayed. You were on the right track by adding a `boolean` value to track if the message had already displayed, but the `while` loop you have will never execute because `isToasted` is set to `false`.

Actually, you don't even need a loop. All you have to do is check if the z-value is between a range of two values. If so, you set the `boolean` to true. If not, you check if the `boolean` is true and the z-value is is above or below the range. Then you can set the `Toast` accordingly, and set the `boolean` to false so that the message will not display a second time.

```
private boolean isReset = true;
private float mMaxValue = 7;
private float mDeadZone = 5;

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float value = event.values[2];

    if(value >= mDeadZone || value <= -mDeadZone) {
        if(isReset && value <= -mMaxValue) {
            Toast.makeText(find_word2.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            isReset = false;
        } else if(isReset && value >= mMaxValue) {
            Toast.makeText(find_word2.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            isReset = false;
        }
    } else {
        isReset = true;
    }
}
```

You could also create a "dead zone" by making the range in the outer `if` statement lower than the maximum value. This would ensure that the user would have to reset the device closer to zero before the `Toast` could be displayed again.

Comment: ah thanks. I tried that and now it works right in showing "wrong" but it doesn't toast "correct" at all !

Comment: @ahmadmohseni Ah, my fault. The `value` should have been wrapped in a `Math.abs()` function as well, or just use a simple `||` operator. I edited the answer, it should work now.

Comment: @ahmadmohseni I made a simple [fiddle](http://ideone.com/wuLL20) that mimics `onSensorChanged`. It outputs the "SensorEvent" z-value, as well as "correct" if the value is equal to or below -7 and "wrong" if the value is equal to or above 7. In this case `isReset` is always true because I always reset the value to zero after every call.

Comment: Thank you for your attention to my problem. now i see that the app toast's "correct". but the first problem is still not resolved. if user keep his device just for some millisecond in tilted position and don't turn it to direct position (-7>value<7), the app toast's multiple times.

Comment: @ahmadmohseni This could be caused by some minor variations in the z-value due to slight movement of the device. Say the value is 7.0, and drops to 6.9 and back to 7.0 (which is barely noticeable), the toast "wrong" will still display. I made an edit showing how you can add a "dead zone" to avoid this issue. This will make sure `isReset` will not return to true unless the value gets closer to zero.

Answer (score 0):

> The difference between do-while and while is that do-while evaluates
>   its expression at the bottom of the loop instead of the top.
>   Therefore, the statements within the do block are always executed at
>   least once.

Comment: This will create an infinite loop for each call to `onSensorChanged()` because the `sensorValue` never changes during a single call. If you remove the loop entirely, this should work as expected.